# How to use union in select clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, union

I have two tables (created here for example) like:

```
X1   Y1
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   4
```

and

```
X2   Y2
a    5
m    6
n    7
b    4
```

And I want the output column:

```
X    Y1   y2
a    1    5
b    2    4
c    3    0
d    4    0
m    0    6
n    0    7
```

What I tried is:

```
SELECT (A.X1 UNION B.X1) AS X, A.Y1,B.Y2
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B
ON A.X1 = B.X2
```

(the query mentioned above is just sample).
After executing this query I am getting error message:

> Syntax error: near UNION in select clause

Can someone tell me what is wrong here. Is there any other option to get the output table in the mentioned format?

Comment: this would be better done with a join instead of a union seeing as you have a common column in your table definitions, also you don't need a union there you could just select one of the 2 or you would get a result like: "aa 1 5" even thought it won't work what you are doing here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`union` is used to join results one after another. You're attempting to `join` results side by side (which you already did!). The only thing you're missing is a `coalesce` call to handle the missing values:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.x1, b.x2) AS x, 
       COALESCE(a.y1, 0) AS y1, 
       COALESCE(b.y2, 0) AS y2
FROM   a 
FULL OUTER JOIN b on a.x1 = b.x2
```

Comment: keep forgetting about coalesce :p

Comment: And naming the result columns so that they don't end up as `"coalesce"`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8b77/7

Comment: @Guffa nice improvement, thanks! I edited my answer to include the column aliases.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [COALESCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html)

> The `COALESCE` function returns the first of its arguments that is not
>   null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null.

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.X1,B.X2) AS X, COALESCE(A.Y1, 0) AS Y1, COALESCE(B.Y2, 0) AS Y2
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B
ON A.X1 = B.X2
```

Comment: Thanks :) I was not knowing about COALESCE  function. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Coalesce(a.x1,b.x1) AS X, coalesce(a.y1,0) as Y1 coalesce(b.y2,0) as Y2
FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN
b ON a.x1 = b.x2
```

You don't need the UNION statement here, the union is used to add a resultset from a select to a resultset from a different select

You just need to use your join here with the correct on statement (which you did correct) and get the x1 or x2 from one of the tables as x1 would be equal to x2 within the same row

EDIT: Added coalesce statements to my query to return value for x if a.x1 does not exist but b.x2 does exist, also added 0 if a field doesn't exist for y1 or y2

Answer (score 1):

The error is because UNION is not command that can be used in the list of columns, it is on set level, you can UNION two selects like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
```

they just need to have same columns

Comment: this wouldn't get him the result he requires though, this would just show results from both tables such as:
>
 X Y 
 a 1
 a 5
>

Comment: that's what I said right? only my values are not formatted properly because I still don't know how to format things in comment box